# Swagger Method not found IncludeXmlComments(System.String)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I've just created a new asp net core 2.0 application and added swagger with nuget.

When i try running the application i got the following error, after enabled stdout logs:

```
Application startup exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenOptions.IncludeXmlComments(System.String)'.
   at Ituran.Framework.Startup.StartupExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<ConfigureServicesExtensions>b__7(SwaggerGenOptions c)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SwaggerGenServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateSwaggerProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenOptions.IncludeXmlComments(System.String)'.
   at Ituran.Framework.Startup.StartupExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<ConfigureServicesExtensions>b__7(SwaggerGenOptions c)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SwaggerGenServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateSwaggerProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
Hosting environment: Localhost
Content root path: {PATH_OF_PROJECT}
Now listening on: http://localhost:23419
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Here is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        private StartupExtensions StartupExtensions { get; set; }
        private IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            StartupExtensions = new StartupExtensions($"{env.EnvironmentName}");
            Configuration = StartupExtensions.Init();
        }



        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            StartupExtensions.ConfigureServicesExtensions(services, Configuration, new SwaggerConfiguration
            {
                Title = "EmergencyEvent Api",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "API de integração HDI"
            }, false);

            // Dependency Injection

            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationProvider, IturanAuthenticationProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<IIturanAuthenticationService, IturanAuthenticationService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            StartupExtensions.ConfigureExtensions(loggerFactory, app, Configuration, new SwaggerConfigurationUrl
            {
                ApiDevelopmentName = "api.emergencyevent",
                ApiStagingName = "api.emergencyevent",
                ApiProductionName = "api.emergencyevent"
            });
        }
    }
```

I've tried to remove swagger configuration from my startup.cs already, but the application still not running.

Comment: "and added swagger" - show the dirty details.

Comment: what do you mean ?  I'll edit the code, then you can see my startup file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the solution (or workaround) was to downgrade Swashbuckle from 2.5 back to 2.4 (which had previously been working fine).